# Starting out with Geb

Tags: groovy, geb

I haven't coded in such a long time and now i'm going headfirst into Geb w/o knowing Groovy, jQuery syntax and generally being very rusty and so i expect to be asking a few questions starting with setup.

I have installed the following - JDK, Eclipse, Groovy-Eclipse plugin

I've downloaded the JARs for WebDriver, Geb, and Geb-Spock.

My intent is to start writing / executing automated scripts (possibly looking to replaced QTP at some point in the future) - is this all i will need? or will I also require something like Grails?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI i'm getting the same error when inputting the sample code into the Groovy Console and into Eclipse (as a groovy project / script)

Comment: I'm trying to be as barebones as possible - i don't think i need to use Grails - do i?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  neither the question is good nor the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is the [Geb mailing list](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/geb/lists).